# Errors/warnings when selecting data from PHP array

Tags: php

I am trying to select data from an array. I am using the following script.

I basically have a function that is supposed to scan the array and find results within the last hour but I think my function has some problems.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $result = 'array(2) {
      ["Status"]=>
      string(3) "001"
      ["CallData"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["item"]=>
        array(36) {
          ["CallRef"]=>
          string(10) "1234567890"
          ["CallStartDate"]=>
          string(10) "2017-01-22"
          ["CallStartTime"]=>
          string(8) "11:59:30"
        }
      }
    }';

    function getFilteredCallsByDate($calls, $since) {
        return new CallbackFilterIterator(new ArrayIterator($calls['CallData']['item']), function ($call) use ($since) {
            return strtotime(sprintf('%s %s', $call['CallStartDate'], $call['CallStartTime'])) >= strtotime($since);
        });
    }

    // limit to last 60 minutes
    foreach (getFilteredCallsByDate($result, '-60 minutes') as $call) {

        var_dump($call);

    }

?>
```

However, when I run this, I get the following errors:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'CallData' in test.php on line 25

Warning: Illegal string offset 'item' in test.php on line 25

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Passed variable is not an array or object, using empty array instead' in test.php:25 

Stack trace: 
#0 test.php(25): ArrayIterator->__construct('a') 
#1 test.php(31): getFilteredCallsByDate('array(2) {\n\t [...', '-60 minutes') 
#2 {main} thrown in test.php on line 25
```

How can I debug these errors and resolve why I'm getting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$result isn't an array, but a string. You have encapsulated it in quotation marks.

Update: Apart from that: Your CallbackFilterIterator goes over each entry in `result["CallData"]["item"]`. So it will, in your example, return:
`"1234567890", "2017-01-22", "11:59:30"`.

What you probably want to do is iterate over `result["CallData"]` rather:

```
<?php
$result = ["Status"=>"001", "CallData" => ["item" => ["CallRef"=>"1234567890", "CallStartDate"=>"2017-01-22", "CallStartTime"=>"11:59:30"]]];
function getFilteredCallsByDate($calls, $since) {
    return new CallbackFilterIterator(new ArrayIterator($calls['CallData']), function ($call) use ($since) {
        return strtotime(sprintf('%s %s', $call['CallStartDate'], $call['CallStartTime'])) >= strtotime($since);
    });
}

foreach (getFilteredCallsByDate($result, '-60 minutes') as $call) {

    var_dump($call);

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I should probably explain this better. `$result` actually stores an array but in the example above I've (stupidly) made it into a string. So the original code is `$result = $client->call("GetCalls");` which returns an array to $result. I'm still getting the same error when I do either.

Comment: I owe the world's biggest hug right now, fjc. It works, it amazingly works!!!! Thank you so so much. No idea how much head scratching I've been doing since 6am here :-/ :-( Thank You.

Comment: Quick tip how I found it easily: I just echoed the value of `$call` inside your closure.

Comment: I did that too, or at least tried, but just didn't have `the knack` to figure out the rest. Very much a big thank you from my end. Hope you have a great day :-)